# Dynamically Buld the Statement

Tags: t-sql

I want dynamically search condition.

This is my table(This is generated dynamically ) this is not a physical table.

```
id Tablename          columnname         Value    |
1  Company            Company_name      Microsoft |
2  Address            Pcity             CA        |
3  Phone              Pnumber           100-4582  |
```

I want search the Value in the particular table , In this tables are already in the database(Company,Address,Phone). dynamically pass the tablename and columnname and search the Value.

Ex

```
Select c.Company_name from Company c join Address a on
    a.companyid=c.companyid join phone p on p.companyid=c.companyid
    where 1=1 and c.company_name like '%Microsoft%' and a.Pcity Like
    '%CA%' and p.Pnumber like '%100-4582%'
```

I want dynamically buld the query and search the condition in the Value column.

How can I do this ..

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain bit more. You can make the above query with the variables as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

what i understood is basically you want to make dynamic query, so i am providing a sample for you

```
create proc dummy_proc

@arg1 varchar(50),
@arg2 int
as

Declare @S varchar(max)  

Set @S='select  * from  tablename where 1=1'

if @arg1<>'' then

set @s=@s+ 'and column1 like''%'+@arg1+%''' 

Execute(@S)
```

hope it helps